# jenkins job taking a long time to go to the next step after exit 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, msbuild, devops, vstest

I have a job on jenkins that runs through msbuild. After the build is complete tests are run through vstest and finally if they succeed, jenkins exits with exit 0. Over here, the job is at a stand still for around 15 mins. Only then, the email plugin is triggered and emails are sent out. What is going on at that time and how can I fix this? 
[pic of exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2NnB.png)

Comment: Please add your `build` and `test` commands.

Comment: Maybe it is  a microsoft mistake. Jenkins works perfectly and ends its execution when command or remote process ends